# Processes dissappear from processlist (MariaDB)

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.1

In my application I need to monitor list of process ids for some database user, so I execute `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command to get information.
The problem is that sometimes some Id dissapears from command output but it comes back on next execution. For me it seems like a bug, what cause this strange behaviour?

Example:

```
1934,1935,1936,1937,1938
1934,1935,1936,1937,1938
1934,1935,1936,1937,1938
1934,1935,1936,1938
1934,1935,1936,1937,1938
```

Version:

```
MariaDB [db_w1]> select @@version;
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 10.1.24-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with the process list? Kill connections of? If so this can just specify a user in the [kill](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/data-manipulation-kill-connection-query/) comand.

Comment: Is "connection pooling" turned on?

Answer (score 0):

Processes, in the MySQL `PROCESS LIST`, are representations of connections from outside the server. A `mysql -h {host}` will create a client connection. They are transient in that, if a client disconnects, the server process no longer exists.

As such a process showing in a process list can no longer be there on subsequent access if the connection was disconnected from the client.

Comment: Could you expand on this a bit more, so the OP can understand the implications of this (and why it would reappear)?